# Couchbase : 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getFilesDir()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, couchbase-lite

I am using Couchbase to store database locally on the device. I have am saving the database from my service class.

```
public void saveToDatabase(String symbol, List<Date> dateList, List<String> closeList){
        CbDatabase db = new CbDatabase(DB_NAME, this);

        // create an object that contains data for a document
        Map<String, Object> docContent = new HashMap<>();
        docContent.put(SYMBOL, symbol);
        docContent.put(DATE, dateList);
        docContent.put(CLOSE, closeList);
        String docId = null;
        try {
            // 1. Create
            docId = db.create(docContent);
            assert(docId != null);
            txt += ("Created doc with id " + docId + "\n");

            txt += ("\n\nRETRIEVE --> ");
            // 2. Retrieve
            docContent= db.retrieve(docId);
            assert(docContent != null);
            txt += ("Retrieved Doc " + String.valueOf(docContent) + "\n");

            txt += ("\n\nDELETE --> ");
            // 4. Delete
            boolean deleted = db.delete(docId);
            assert(deleted == true);
            txt += ("Deleted document with id: " + docId + "\n");

            txt += ("\n\nSUCCESS.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is cdDatabase Helper Class which I am using for Couchbase Database I don't understand where I might be going I am new to Couchbase.

```
 public CbDatabase(String dbname, Context context){

        this.ctx = context;
        /* Manages access to databases */
        try {
            manager = new Manager( new AndroidContext(ctx), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS );
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            ErrorChecker.ShowException(ctx, R.string.err_create_manager, e );
            return;
        }
        // create a name for the database and make sure the name is legal
        // Only the following characters are valid:
        // abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_$()+-/
        if ( ! Manager.isValidDatabaseName(dbname)) {
            ErrorChecker.showError( ctx, R.string.err_db_name );
            return;
        }
        // get existing db with that name
        // or create a new one if it doesn't exist
        try {
            database = manager.getDatabase(dbname);
        }
        catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
            ErrorChecker.ShowException(ctx, R.string.err_no_db, e );
            return;
        }
    }
```

Here is the LOGCAT for the NullPointer

j

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getFilesDir()' on a null object reference
com.android.stockhawk W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:203)
com.android.stockhawk W/System.err:     at com.couchbase.lite.android.AndroidContext.getFilesDir(AndroidContext.java:40)
com.android.stockhawk W/System.err:     at com.couchbase.lite.Manager.<init>(Manager.java:117)
com.android.stockhawk W/System.err:     at com.android.stockhawk.quotes.db.CbDatabase.<init>(CbDatabase.java:41)
com.android.stockhawk W/System.err:     at com.android.stockhawk.service.StockTaskService.saveToDatabase(StockTaskService.java:191)
com.android.stockhawk W/System.err:     at com.android.stockhawk.service.StockTaskService.getStockQuotes(StockTaskService.jcom.android.stockhawk W/System.err:     at com.android.stockhawk.service.StockTaskService.onRunTask(StockTaskService.java:141)
com.android.stockhawk W/System.err:     at com.android.stockhawk.service.StockIntentService.onHandleIntent(StockIntentService.java:39)
```

Comment: From the logs, it appears that context is null when the `CbDatabase` method gets called. Is the `saveToDatabase` method located in an Activity subclass? This answer explains how to grab the context depending on where the Couchbase Lite manager gets instantiate in the lifecycle of your app http://stackoverflow.com/a/3572553/1908348

Comment: This is a common mistake.  You most likely haven't started your service properly before using it.  Search for "android service context null" and you'll find lots of help.